# Select rows not having particular entries in the history

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

Device table

```
+----------+----------+
| DeviceId | Name     |
+----------+----------+
|        10| Dev10    |
|        20| Dev20    |
|        30| Dev30    |
+----------+----------+
```

History table

```
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| DeviceId | State |      TimeStamp      |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
|        10|     0 | 06/09/2021 11:10:01 |
|        20|     1 | 06/09/2021 11:10:02 |
|        30|     0 | 06/09/2021 11:10:03 |
|        10|     0 | 06/09/2021 11:10:04 |
|        20|     0 | 06/09/2021 11:10:05 |
|        30|     1 | 06/09/2021 11:10:05 |
|        10|     2 | 06/09/2021 11:10:06 |
|        20|     0 | 06/09/2021 11:10:06 |
|        30|     0 | 06/09/2021 11:10:06 |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

I can select DeviceId's that have ever been in state=2

```
SELECT *
FROM Device A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM History B
             WHERE A.ID = B.DeviceId and B.[State]=2
             ORDER BY B.TimeStamp DESC) as B
order by A.Id
```

The question is how to select devices that **have never been** in State=2.

The result should be:

```
+----------+----------+
| DeviceId | Name     |
+----------+----------+
|        20| Dev20    |
|        30| Dev30    |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: `where not exists (select * from history where deviceID = a.deviceId and state = 2)`. Although I usually prefer something like `left join History h on h.deviceId = a.deviceId and h.state = 2 where h.deviceId is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know what does not exist, the natural syntax is to use `exists`

```
select *
from Device d
where not exists (
  select * 
  from History h 
  where h.DeviceId = d.DeviceId and h.state = 2
)
```